# How should I go about selecting rows with thousands of columns?

Tags: database, cassandra

There are about a couple million records that look like this.

`idA(text), idB(int), prop1(boolean), prop2(boolean), ..., prop6000(boolean) (more prop's can be added later on)`

And the primary task will be finding records with some combination of prop values. 
eg: `SELECT idA, idB WHERE prop30=true AND prop1987=false AND ... AND prop5754=true`

If the `SELECT` speed were the main concern, how should I go about this problem?

--

I was thinking about defining the props as a list of int and adding values only where the value are true and use CONATINS when SELECTing.
ie: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('id1', 1, [10, 24, 2977])` -> if prop10, prop24 and prop 2977 were true

But then it is said that the secondary index does not scale very well and should not be used heavily.
Does it hold true even for lists? (I'm thinking maybe it's different for lists as they are sorted?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key things in Cassandra query performance is that you must - MUST - hit a partition before applying an index filter. In addition, when you apply multiple index filters, it only hits one index and filters the rest in mem (i.e. only one index is used). In your query, you're not hitting a partition, and as such, it'll be a cluster wide query, that is most likely to timeout.

In cassandra 3.0, the rules will be somewhat relaxed with the introduction of global indexes. Even then, your query won't really work that great.

If all your properties are booleans, you can consider storing them as a bitfield. One integer can then hold 64 flags. That might be more efficient. One the querying side, you will still need to find a partition key by which you'll hit a partition. With the flags approach, you can simply read in the integer and do a filter on the clientside. All rows in the partition will be loaded, but unless you've got hundreds of thousands of rows in the same partition, it shouldn't be a problem.

If you trully don't have a partition key, and all you can look up is props (as in your example above), then you'll need to manually carry out indexing. Built in indexes won't really work that well, and you can choose to create index tables yourself (which may be quite difficult) or use an indexing service like Lucene, which will allow you to do the search quickly.